# git fatal: unable to read d7052036c8f017b58e7c11806cdbfcb9e9215757

Tags: git, github

i use

> git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c
> log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin
> refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main --set-upstream

from Intellij IDE, to commit and push all my project to GitHub, but i get error:

> ```
> fatal: unable to read d7052036c8f017b58e7c11806cdbfcb9e9215757
> remote: fatal: early EOF        
> error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:misterrevo/myboard.git'
> ```

Comment: The line that *doesn't* start with `remote:` here (`fatal: unable to read d7052036c8f017b58e7c11806cdbfcb9e9215757`) indicates that your (local) repository is damaged. It's not clear what damaged it, but the usual suspect for a problem like this is that you've set up your repository in a cloud-synced folder, and the cloud-syncing software broke it.